# MethodCallExpression for Count

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I'm trying to count the number of distinct values in a property of a generic type.

I have `Select` and `Distinct` working, I'm having trouble calling `Count`.

It's true that I could just explicitly call `.Count()` as in the example, but I'll need this to be working for when I come to do other aggregations such as `Sum`, etc.

Also, how do I get the resulting `int`? I'm thinking `.First()`?

```
    {
        public string S { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        private static readonly List<Thing> Things = new List<Thing>()
        {
            new Thing(){ S = "dE" },
            new Thing(){ S = null },
            new Thing(){ S = "55" },
            new Thing(){ S = "efg5" },
            new Thing(){ S = "55" }

        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Thing).GetProperty(columnName);
            ParameterExpression z = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Thing), "z");
            MemberExpression me = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(z, pi);
            LambdaExpression le = Expression.Lambda(me, z);
            UnaryExpression lq = Expression.Quote(le);
            MethodCallExpression select = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Select", new Type[] { q.ElementType, pi.PropertyType }, q.Expression, lq);
            MethodCallExpression distinct = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Distinct", new Type[] { pi.PropertyType }, select);
            MethodCallExpression count = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Count", new Type[] { pi.PropertyType }, distinct);

            IQueryable<Thing> q = Things.AsQueryable();

            int i = q.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(select).Distinct().Count(); // Works
            int j = q.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(distinct).Count(); // Works

            var wtf = q.Provider.CreateQuery<int>(count); // System.ArgumentException: 'Argument expression is not valid'

           int k = wtf.First(); // This feels wrong.
        }


Edit: `IQueryable<Thing> q = Things.AsQueryable();`
```

Comment: What is `q`? This seems like a question about whatever library provides `q.Provider.CreateQuery`

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's `Things.AsQueryable()`

Comment: I tried to reproduce this (without using `q.Provider.CreateQuery`) and failed: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nrr2Gx . Please create a full [mcve] which reproduces your problem.

Comment: From [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/SequenceQuery.cs,86), it looks like `.AsQueryable().CreateQuery<T>()` only works for expressions which themselves return `IQueryable<T>`. Why are you using `IQueryable` here anyway?

Comment: I see you've got it to work by _not_ using `.Provider.CreateQuery` but by doing something else instead.

Comment: I'm doing `.Provider.CreateQuery ` because that's what works for filtering and paging so I just assumed that the same pattern would work for aggregations.

Comment: Indeed, I showed that the actual construction of the expressions is fine and works, so the issue is with `q.Provider.CreateQuery` -- at the time, I didn't know where that came from, so that was as close as I could get

Comment: Are you passing the resulting `IQuerable` to a database or something? Or are you just using this as a faster alternative to normal reflection (although I doubt using `IQueryable` here would speed anything up)? If it's the latter, don't go near `IQuerable` at all, stay with `IEnumerable`, like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/laYc1O. `Enumerable.AsQueryable` is essentially a niche-case hack, which you normally shouldn't go anywhere near

Comment: It's backed by EntityFramework. It's producing paged, filterable, sortable tables in MVC with aggregates specified using attributes on the POCOs.

Comment: I don't follow how your `private static readonly List<Thing> Things` is backed by EF? There's no EF anywhere in your question.

Comment: Well, no I was trying to make a simple example to show the problem.
In the real one it's a `DbSet`.

Comment: Right, but the exception that's reported in your question is thrown by the query provider that you get when you call `AsQueryable()`. Not by an EF query provider. So in trying to make a "simple example", you've created something which contains an entirely different problem, I think.

Answer (score 1):

[IQueryProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryprovider?view=netcore-3.1) interface provides two set of methods - [CreateQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryprovider.createquery?view=netcore-3.1) and [Execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryprovider.execute?view=netcore-3.1).

The former is for *building* queries from expressions which represent `IQueryable` result, e.g. with your sample

```
IQueryable<string> selectQuery = q.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(select);
IQueryable<string> distinctQuery = q.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(distinct);
```

while the later is for *executing* queries from expressions which represent immediate result (like `Count`, `Sum`, `Max`, `First` etc.), e.g. with your sample

```
int countResult = q.Provider.Execute<int>(count);
```

You can actually see that in [Queryable methods implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Linq.Queryable/src/System/Linq/Queryable.cs). When called, all methods simply create expression representing call to themselves, which then is passed to either `CreateQuery` or `Execute` depending of the method return type.